# Fancybox Pop-up Login - Page only opens in modal box

Tags: html, modal-dialog, fancybox

I'm trying to create a log-in page using Fancybox.  Everyhing works fine, except when I redirect the user to the logged-in page, it keeps opening up in the modal dialog box.

How can I reference the parent?

`parent.opener.location.href` is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the following worked:

```
parent.document.location.href
```